# Point-free pipe range with Ramdajs

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

I have my function that creates ranges:

```
const range = from => to => step => ....
```

And i want to create another function that do something with that range, but i want to use pipe.

For example i want to get the sum of the range.

```
const sum = ...

const getSum = pipe(
    range(),
    sum,
)
```

I can to the following:

```
  const getSum = from => to => {
       return sum(range(from)(to)(1))
    }
```

But can I do it with ramdajs and to be point free.

For example:

```
const getSum = pipe(
   range..///here,
   sum
)
```

pipe, sum and range are my implementations.

But i am not sure how to do it point-free style.

**Note that range is function that return function for easier currying.**

```
range(0)(10)(1)
```

Thank you

More description:

Imagine i have count and split functions.
This is regular function:

```
 const numChars = str => count(split('', str))
```

This is point-free style (imag

```
const numChars = pipe(split(''), count)
```

I want to the the same but with the range above

Comment: If your `range` is fully curried, then `pipe` will be able to pass only a single parameter to it.

Comment: But i dont have reference to the parameter and the function: pipe(range, {here}, ...)

Comment: "*is function that return function for easier currying*"? I think you mean "is a curried function for easier partial application".

Comment: Yes, correct but i dont know how to pipe with two arguments or more since getSum takes 2 arguments as well. Or maybe is better not to be point-free function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compose with a function taking more than one argument, use composition multiple times - although you need to use [`R.o`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#o) instead of `pipe` or `compose`:

```
// sum: [Number] -> Number
// range: Number -> Number -> [Number]
// getSum: Number -> Number -> Number
const getSum = R.o(R.o(R.sum), R.range);
```

---

To supply the last argument of a curried function, the easiest Ramda solution is using [a placeholder](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#module.exports):

```
// stepRange: Number -> Number -> Number -> [Number]
// range: Number -> Number -> [Number]
const range = stepRange(R.__, R.__, 1);
```

but this only works with functions created by Ramda's own `curryN` or `curry`, not with manually curried functions. With those, you can only [`R.flip`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip) until you can partially apply the first argument:

```
// stepRange: from -> to -> step -> range
// flip(stepRange): to -> from -> step -> range
// o(flip, stepRange): from -> step -> to -> range
// flip(o(flip, stepRange)): step -> from -> to -> range
// range: from -> to -> range
const range = R.flip(R.o(R.flip, stepRange))(1);
```

I cannot really recommend doing this. Everything is possible, but this is unreadable. Just write out the parameters:

```
const getSum = R.o(R.o(R.sum), R.flip(R.o(R.flip, stepRange))(1));
// vs
const getSum = from => to => R.sum(stepRange(from)(to)(1));
```

Comment: Ahh, now that I see an answer, I actually understand the question!